# nodemon installed but not working on win10

Tags: nodemon

I have installed nodemon (tried locally, globally and as dev dependencies), I get the message that nodemon is properly installed:

```
+ nodemon@1.19.0
updated 1 package and audited 2357 packages in 24.027s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "tests-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0"
  }
}
```

But when I run it, I get the message that nodemon does not exist (the message is in french):

```
'nodemon' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this:

Change your "scripts" in package.json like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
```

and then start nodemon with `npm run dev`.

`npm run start` will the normal node server, and `dev` the nodemon.